Can I replace 2 Zinsco single pole 35amp breakers with one 35amp 2-pole?
For our dryer...We have two old Zinsco 35a single poles and they only have one black wire each. If the breakers can be replaced with one 2-pole 35amp, which connector or slot gets what wire? Or does it matter? They're both black. I'm guessing if I meter them one would be 120 and the other 240? Is there a dedicated slot for either?

Pictures of panel and dryer receptacle and model # of dryer would be helpful.

...have you considered replacing the panel?  Zinsco breakers are known to be unreliable (including sometimes not turning the power off when you go to flip them off)...

We are renters so replacing the panel would definitely need to be taken care of by the owner, I was hoping to take care of it myself and keep out of the laundry mat this week. I've replaced breakers in this panel in the past, but was recommended to swap two single pole 35s for one double pole.

@BrandenMcAfee What country/state/province/whatever are you in? In the US replacing breakers in a rental can't be done by you or the owner. It must be done by a licensed electrician.

It can't? Or shouldn't? I don't need a moral compass here i just need my dryer to stop tripping a breaker when the heating element kicks on. It runs fine on the Air Only setting, but when on a normal dry mode or cycle it trips the breaker.

@BrandenMcAfee All Zinsco breakers are defective. If you mess with the panel, you could burn down the entire building and be held personally responsible. Replacing the entire panel is the only responsible option.

Most likely the actual problem is your dryer is defective. The failure mode for Zinsco breakers is that they don’t trip on overload, or don’t cut off power when manually switched off. If your breaker is tripping when you use the dryer heat, the dryer probably is drawing far too much current (likely due to  short). Replace (or repair) the dryer.

New Panel Time
If this wasn't a Zinsco then I would say:

Standard US dryers are 30A not 35A
A double pole breaker is correct because with a dryer you need common shutoff (as is the case with any 240V load) and common trip (because it is actually a 240V/120V load. Two single breakers don't give you common trip, though properly handle tied they can give you common shutoff.
A 240V circuit has 120V from each hot to neutral and 240V (in some buildings 208V) between hots. Wire colors mostly don't matter.

But you have a Zinsco, and those are known problem panels. So the first step is to determine whether it is even safe to continue using the panel, and figure out what would be involved in replacing it.
